# How to make Volume Slider for mac application

Tags: xcode, macos, avaudioplayer, avplayer, floating

I write  application for Mac OS. So it will be audio player. Now i try to make volume slider from AVPLayer but i have some problem. So i tried this code:

```
in h file:

IBOutlet NSLider *volumeSlider;
IBOutlet NSButton *button;
AVPlayer *myplayer;

-(IBAction)changeslider;

in m file:

[myplayer.volume=volumeSlider.value]
```

So i have error Assigning to 'float' from incompatible type 'id'. So what i doing wrong? I know hot to make volume slider in IOS from MPMVolumeView but Mac OS used ONLY AVPlayer or AVAudioPlayer. Thanks for answers.

So i have some idea with + or - volume from buttons.

```
NSString *change
change = @"%@", +1;
iPodplayer.volume=change;
```

But i also have error with float...

Comment: Your syntax of method call is incorrect. I think you are a beginner and give some time to learn the basics,

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: Since he is asking a basic question, he currently _is_ learning the basics. Don't demotivate him.

Comment: @DarkDust: Yes I know, as we can see few others syntax and typo errors. Thats is why I commented. And I am sorry if he gets hurt by my  comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do:

```
myplayer.volume = volumeSlider.floatValue;
```

The `volume` property on `AVPlayer` wants a float, yet in the first example you tried to assign it a value of type `id`, and in the second a value of type `NSString`. BTW, the expression `change = @"%@", 1;` is not doing what you think it does: it assigns a string `%@` (really the percent sign and an "at" sign), then evaluates the number 1 and just ignores it.

Comment: Now your answers explains hence +1.